# $_POST undefined from remote server POST

Tags: api, drupal, post

I am writing a Drupal 7 module which is listening for HTTP POST messages to be sent by a 3rd party remote application. For testing I am sending messages using the Firefox Poster extension.

If I POST the message, the following code fails to place any value in my local vars (I get 'undefined index'):

```
$transId = urldecode($_POST['c2s_transaction_id']);
```

However, if I send the message using GET, the vars get populated fine with the following code:

```
$transId = urldecode($_REQUEST['c2s_transaction_id']);
```

This is true on both my local WAMP setup and on a shared hosting package.

I have never worked with HTTP POST messages before and have no idea where the problem might be. Could it be Drupal, the web server, or my code? Can anyone suggest how I might resolve this?

Many thanks,
Polly

Answer (score 0):

Drupal removes the $_POST/$_GET in the system, just use $_REQUEST instead.

Comment: I now have this working using my original code:

    $transId = urldecode($_POST['c2s_transaction_id']);

My solution was to change the tool I am testing with. It still does not work posting with the Firefox Poster extension. However, it does work if I use this online tool: http://hurl.it

Unfortunately my knowledge of HTTP is limited so I do not know why this is the case but at least I am more confident to progress towards a live situation.

@boy: Thanks for your response but it does appear that $_POST works within Drupal 7.

Thanks
Polly

Comment: @Polly, sorry about that, I seemed to remember that Drupal emptied it. Could you provide a screen shot of the Firefox extension and how you are doing it now?